# Websocket for wsgi, which compatible with werkzeug

Tags: websocket, wsgi, werkzeug

Need websocket wsgi library, which is compatible with werkzeug.

Answer (score 2):

Twisted provides a WSGIResource to run under Twisted Web. Autobahn provides a WebSocketResource to run under Twisted Web. So you can combine both (I have done that) - if that is what you mean by "websocket wsgi library".

For the latter: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/websocket/echo_site

Disclaimer: I am main author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check `gevent` especially `gevent.socketio` if you are just getting started.

http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Take a look at following tutorial, kind of long, but it gives you nice way in.

http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/07/realtime-web-chat-with-socketio-and.html

Answer (score 0):

I've recently hacked the Werkzeug debugger so it works nicely with gevent-socketio:

https://github.com/aldanor/SocketIO-Flask-Debug